# One to One vs. Onto

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is there a one to one function mapping the positive integers to the open interval (0,1)?

Is there an onto function mapping the positive integers onto the open interval (0,1)?

I'm having trouble thinking of an example for either, or a proof of the impossibility for either.

Comment: You can map them injectively by $n\mapsto 1/n$, but "onto" is impossible. You may look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set)..

Answer (score 3):

For the first, consider e.g. $n\mapsto \frac{1}{n+1}$. It is injective (can you see why)?
For the second, it is not possible: what do you know about countability and uncountability? And what would a surjection from $\mathbb{N}^\ast$ to $(0,1)$ imply?

Answer (score 0):

One-to-One, yes:

$$f(n)=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Onto, no:

$$|\mathbb{N}|<|\mathbb{R}|=|(0,1)|$$